# Why is my list not sorted as expected?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a `dict()` called `twitter_users` which holds `TwitterUser` objects as values. I want those objects to be sorted by the field `mentioned`. However, using `sorted()` does not work as I expect. I provide a `lambda` function that is supposed to determine if user `a` or user `b` was mentioned more often.

```
srt = sorted(twitter_users.values(), 
         cmp=(lambda a,b: 
              True if a.mentioned > b.mentioned else False))

for s in srt:
    print s.mentioned
```

Unfortunately this is not working and the list `srt` isn't sorted in any way.

How can I make this work?

Comment: in any case, this is better written as `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.mentioned)`

Comment: What's the type of `mentioned`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `cmp` function should return an integer, `0` when equal, `1` or higher when `a` should come after `b` and `-1` or lower if they should come in the opposite order.

You instead return `False` and `True`. Because the Python boolean type is a subclass of `int`, these objects have the values `0` and `1` when interpreted as integers. You never return `-1`, so you are confusing the sorting algorithm; you tell it the order of `a` and `b` is either always 'equal' or `a` should come before `b`, always. But the sorting algorithm sometimes asks for `a` and `b` swapped, in which case you gave it conflicting information!

Note that your expression is rather verbose; `True if a.mentioned > b.mentioned else False` could just be simplified to `a.mentioned > b.mentioned`; the `>` operator already produces either `True` or `False`. Using simple integers you can see that that is not going to produce expected results:

```
>>> sorted([4, 2, 5, 3, 8], cmp=lambda a, b: a > b)
[4, 2, 5, 3, 8]
```

while actually returning `-1`, `0`, or `1` does work:

```
>>> sorted([4, 2, 5, 3, 8], cmp=lambda a, b: 1 if a > b else 0 if a == b else -1)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 8]
```

or instead of such a verbose expression, just use the built-in [`cmp()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp); for your case you'd use that like this:

```
srt = sorted(twitter_users.values(), cmp=lambda a, b: cmp(a.mentioned, b.mentioned))
```

But you shouldn't really use `cmp` *at all*; there is a far simpler (and more efficient) option. Just use the `key` function instead, which simply returns the `mentioned` attribute:

```
srt = sorted(twitter_users.values(), key=lambda v: v.mentioned)
```

The `key` function produces values by which the actual sort takes place; this function is used to produce a [*Schwartzian transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). Such a transform is more efficient because it is only called O(n) times, while the `cmp` function is called O(n log n) times.

Because you are only accessing an attribute, instead of a `lambda` you can use a [`operator.attrgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) to do the attribute fetching for you:

```
from operator import attrgetter

srt = sorted(twitter_users.values(), key=attrgetter('mentioned'))
```